# How to disable SuSEfirewall2?

Tags: firewall, opensuse

How can I disable SuSEfirewall2 from the shell (without yast)?

We use OpenSuSE 12.3

I tried it:

```
workdevel123:~ # systemctl disable SuSEfirewall2.service
```

But I think this is not the solution:

```
workdevel123:~ # systemctl is-enabled SuSEfirewall2.service
Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5):

At least in openSUSE 12.1 the Firewall is still separated in two components in `/etc/init.d`:

```
# systemctl disable SuSEfirewall2_setup.service
SuSEfirewall2_setup.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig SuSEfirewall2_setup off
# systemctl disable SuSEfirewall2_init.service
SuSEfirewall2_init.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig SuSEfirewall2_init off
```

Using systemctl rather than just `chkconfig --set SuSEfirewall2_setup off` should "more future proof", though.

The order is important. _setup depends on _init.

Comment: Beware to do this remotely it might interrupt your connection. I was dropped out by doing this and had to restart the server.

Answer (score 4):

The following works in OpenSUSE 13.2:

> /sbin/SuSEfirewall2 off

(from http://binwaheed.blogspot.com/2011/02/opensuse-turn-firewall-off.html)

Answer (score 1):

Although `/sbin/SuSEfirewall2 off` is correct, you can also do it with `systemctl`:

```
systemctl -q is-enabled SuSEfirewall2 && systemctl disable SuSEfirewall2
systemctl -q is-active SuSEfirewall2 && systemctl stop SuSEfirewall2
```